# The relation of a set $ A$ and the closure of ${\rm conv} B$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We have $A,\ B,\ C\subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$, nonempty, $C$ is bounded and $A+C \subset B+C$. Prove that $A \subset {\rm cl}({\rm conv}B)$.

For ${\rm cl}({\rm conv}B)$, I started using the definition with sequences of a closed set, but I don't know how to reffer to the information that $C$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Here we need the condition where $C$ is bounded : If not, assume
that $C = \mathbb{R}^p$. Hence for any $A,\ B$ we have $A+C\subset
B+C$

Assume that $C$ is bounded and $A+C\subset B+C$ Hence $A+C \subset
X+ C$ where $X ={\rm cl\ conv} \ B$. Assume that $a\in A-X$. Hence
there is a plane $l$ s.t. $l$ is between $a$ and $X$, since $X$ is
convex.

Here we can assume that origin $o$ is in $C$, without generality.

There is $v\in C$ s.t. $v$ is orthogonal to $l$ and $|v|$ is
largest. Hence $a+v \in X+C$, which is a contradiction. Hence
$A\subset X$.